# Calculate the daily midnight time from current timestamp

Tags: c++, c++17, poco-libraries

Like suppose Current time is 2021-05-16 22:42 then midnight time be 2021-05-17 00:00:00 at 12 when time change.

I want to calculate the time left in midnight to come from the current time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the poco library, does it contain time capabilities? A quick glance at the documentation has me leaning towards no, but I might have easily overlooked something.

Comment: you can use c++ standard and std::chrono

Comment: So why is the poco library tagged?

Comment: we use mostly poco in development and its a c++ wrapper, But the Timestamp and other can be easily calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    struct tm tm;
    std::string s("2013-12-04 15:03");
    strptime(s.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", &tm);
    struct tm tm1 = tm;
    tm1.tm_mday = tm1.tm_mday +1;
    tm1.tm_hour = 0;
    tm1.tm_min = 0;
    double secs = std::difftime(mktime(&tm1), mktime(&tm));
    std::cout<<secs<<" seconds\n";
    return 0;
}
```